# проверка на выигрыш

Tags: python, pyqt

делаю "крестики-нолики" на pyqt5. не могу сделать так, чтобы проверяло победил ты или нет. с одной комбинацией получилось, а с двумя - нет. как сделать?

```
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QFileDialog,QPushButton
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QLabel
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QSize
import sys


class x_vs_o(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.game()
    def game(self):
        self.q = 1

        self.setGeometry(500,250,500,300)

        self.setWindowTitle('X vs 0 by LTV253')
        app.setWindowIcon(QIcon('icon.png'))

        self.pix = QPixmap('setka.png', '')
        self.pi = QLabel(self)
        self.pi.move(0,0)
        self.pi.resize(300,300)
        self.pi.setPixmap(self.pix)
        self.qw = QPushButton(self)
        self.qw.move(350,100)
        self.qw.resize(100,10)
        self.qw.clicked.connect(self.x12)

        # создаем элемент QLabel
        self.im = QLabel(self)
        self.im.move(0, 0)

        self.setka1 = QPixmap('x.png', '')
        self.image1 = QLabel(self)
        self.image1.move(1, 1)
        self.image1.resize(95,95)
        self.setka12 = QPixmap('n1.png', '')
        self.image12 = QLabel(self)
        self.image12.move(101,1)
        self.image12.resize(95,95)
        self.image123 = QLabel(self)
        self.image123.move(201,1)
        self.image123.resize(95,95)
        self.image2 = QLabel(self)
        self.image2.move(1,101)
        self.image2.resize(95,95)
        self.image21 = QLabel(self)
        self.image21.move(101,101)
        self.image21.resize(95,95)
        self.image213 = QLabel(self)
        self.image213.move(201,101)
        self.image213.resize(95,95)
        self.image43 = QLabel(self)
        self.image43.move(1,201)
        self.image43.resize(95,95)
        self.image431 = QLabel(self)
        self.image431.move(101,201)
        self.image431.resize(95,95)
        self.image4312 = QLabel(self)
        self.image4312.move(201,201)
        self.image4312.resize(95,95)

        self.o1 = QPushButton('', self)
        self.o1.move(0,0)
        self.o1.resize(100,100)
        self.o1.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);\n"
                                      "border: none;")

        self.o1.clicked.connect(self.hodo1)
        self.o12 = QPushButton('', self)
        self.o12.move(101, 0)
        self.o12.resize(100, 100)
        self.o12.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);\n"
                              "border: none;")

        self.o12.clicked.connect(self.hodo12)
        self.o13 = QPushButton('', self)
        self.o13.move(201, 0)
        self.o13.resize(100, 100)
        self.o13.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);\n"
                              "border: none;")

        self.o13.clicked.connect(self.hodo128)
        self.o14 = QPushButton('', self)
        self.o14.move(0, 101)
        self.o14.resize(100, 100)
        self.o14.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);\n"
                               "border: none;")

        self.o14.clicked.connect(self.hodo123)

        self.o15 = QPushButton('', self)
        self.o15.move(101,101)
        self.o15.resize(100,100)
        self.o15.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);\n"
                                      "border: none;")

        self.o15.clicked.connect(self.hodo124)
        self.o16 = QPushButton('', self)
        self.o16.move(201, 101)
        self.o16.resize(100, 100)
        self.o16.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);\n"
                              "border: none;")

        self.o16.clicked.connect(self.hodo125)
        self.o17 = QPushButton('', self)
        self.o17.move(0, 201)
        self.o17.resize(100, 100)
        self.o17.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);\n"
                              "border: none;")

        self.o17.clicked.connect(self.hodo126)
        self.o18 = QPushButton('', self)
        self.o18.move(101, 201)
        self.o18.resize(100, 100)
        self.o18.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);\n"
                               "border: none;")

        self.o18.clicked.connect(self.hodo127)
        self.o19 = QPushButton('',self)
        self.o19.move(201,201)
        self.o19.resize(100,100)
        self.o19.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);\n"
                               "border: none;")
        self.o19.clicked.connect(self.hodo129)

    def hodo129(self):
        self.o19.setEnabled(False)
        print(1)
        q = self.q
        if q == 1:
            self.image4312.setPixmap(self.setka1)

            self.q = q + 1
            self.xis1 = 1
        elif self.q == 2:
            self.image4312.setPixmap(self.setka12)
            self.q = self.q + 1
            self.ois1 = 1
        if q == 3:
            self.image4312.setPixmap(self.setka1)

            self.q = q + 1
            self.xis1 = 1
        elif self.q == 4:
            self.image4312.setPixmap(self.setka12)
            self.q = self.q + 1
            self.ois1 = 1
        if q == 5:
            self.image4312.setPixmap(self.setka1)

            self.q = q + 1
            self.xis1 = 1
        elif self.q == 6:
            self.image4312.setPixmap(self.setka12)
            self.q = self.q + 1
            self.ois1 = 1
        if q == 7:
            self.image4312.setPixmap(self.setka1)

            self.q = q + 1
            self.xis1 = 1

        elif q == 8:
            self.image4312.setPixmap(self.setka12)
            self.q = self.q + 1
            self.ois1 = 1

        if q == 9:
            self.image4312.setPixmap(self.setka1)
            self.q = self.q + 1
            self.xis1 = 15
    def hodo127(self):
        self.o18.setEnabled(False)
        q = self.q
        if q == 1:
            self.image431.setPixmap(self.setka1)

            self.q = q + 1
            self.xis2 = 1
        elif self.q == 2:
            self.image431.setPixmap(self.setka12)
            self.q = self.q + 1
            self.ois2 = 1
        if q == 3:
            self.image431.setPixmap(self.setka1)

            self.q = q + 1
            self.xis2 = 1
        elif self.q == 4:
            self.image431.setPixmap(self.setka12)
            self.q = self.q + 1
            self.ois2 = 1
        if q == 5:
            self.image431.setPixmap(self.setka1)

            self.q = q + 1
            self.xis1 = 1
        elif self.q == 6:
            self.image431.setPixmap(self.setka12)
            self.q = self.q + 1
            self.ois2 = 1
        if q == 7:
            self.image431.setPixmap(self.setka1)

            self.q = q + 1
            self.xis2 = 1
        elif self.q == 8:
            self.image431.setPixmap(self.setka12)
            self.q = self.q + 1
            self.ois2 = 1
        if q == 9:
            self.image431.setPixmap(self.setka1)
            self.q = self.q + 1
            self.xis2 = 1
    def hodo126(self):
        self.o17.setEnabled(False)
        q = self.q
        if q == 1:
            self.image43.setPixmap(self.setka1)

            self.q = q + 1
            self.xis3 = 1
        elif self.q == 2:
            self.image43.setPixmap(self.setka12)
            self.q = self.q + 1
            self.ois3 = 1
        if q == 3:
            self.image43.setPixmap(self.setka1)

            self.q = q + 1
            self.xis3 = 1
        elif self.q == 4:
            self.image43.setPixmap(self.setka12)
            self.q = self.q + 1
            self.ois3 = 1
        if q == 5:
            self.image43.setPixmap(self.setka1)

            self.q = q + 1
            self.xis3 = 1
        elif self.q == 6:
            self.image43.setPixmap(self.setka12)
            self.q = self.q + 1
            self.ois3 = 1
        if q == 7:
            self.image43.setPixmap(self.setka1)

            self.q = q + 1
            self.xis3 = 1
        elif self.q == 8:
            self.image43.setPixmap(self.setka12)
            self.q = self.q + 1
            self.ois3 = 1
        if q == 9:
            self.image43.setPixmap(self.setka1)
            self.q = self.q + 1
            self.xis3 = 1
    def hodo125(self):
        self.o16.setEnabled(False)
        q = self.q
        if q == 1:
            self.image213.setPixmap(self.setka1)

            self.q = q + 1
            self.xis4 = 1
        elif self.q == 2:
            self.image213.setPixmap(self.setka12)
            self.q = self.q + 1
            self.ois4 = 1
        if q == 3:
            self.image213.setPixmap(self.setka1)

            self.q = q + 1
            self.xis4 = 1
        elif self.q == 4:
            self.image213.setPixmap(self.setka12)
            self.q = self.q + 1
            self.ois4 = 1
        if q == 5:
            self.image213.setPixmap(self.setka1)

            self.q = q + 1
            self.xis4 = 1
        elif self.q == 6:
            self.image213.setPixmap(self.setka12)
            self.q = self.q + 1
            self.ois4 = 1
        if q == 7:
            self.image213.setPixmap(self.setka1)

            self.q = q + 1
            self.xis4 = 1
        elif self.q == 8:
            self.image213.setPixmap(self.setka12)
            self.q = self.q + 1
            self.ois4 = 1
        if q == 9:
            self.image213.setPixmap(self.setka1)
            self.q = self.q + 1
            self.xis4 = 1
    def hodo124(self):
        self.o15.setEnabled(False)
        q = self.q
        if q == 1:
            self.image21.setPixmap(self.setka1)

            self.q = q + 1
            self.xis5 = 1
        elif self.q == 2:
            self.image21.setPixmap(self.setka12)
            self.q = self.q + 1
            self.ois5 = 1
        if q == 3:
            self.image21.setPixmap(self.setka1)

            self.q = q + 1
            self.xis5 = 1
        elif self.q == 4:
            self.image21.setPixmap(self.setka12)
            self.q = self.q + 1
            self.ois5 = 1
        if q == 5:
            self.image21.setPixmap(self.setka1)

            self.q = q + 1
            self.xis5 = 1
        elif self.q == 6:
            self.image21.setPixmap(self.setka12)
            self.q = self.q + 1
            self.ois5 = 1
        if q == 7:
            self.image21.setPixmap(self.setka1)

            self.q = q + 1
            self.xis5 = 1
        elif self.q == 8:
            self.image21.setPixmap(self.setka12)
            self.q = self.q + 1
            self.ois5 = 1
        if q == 9:
            self.image21.setPixmap(self.setka1)
            self.q = self.q + 1
            self.xis5 = 1
    def hodo123(self):
        self.o14.setEnabled(False)
        q = self.q
        if q == 1:
            print(21)
            self.image2.setPixmap(self.setka1)

            self.q = q + 1
            self.xis6 = 1
        elif self.q == 2:
            self.image2.setPixmap(self.setka12)
            self.q = self.q + 1
            self.ois6 = 1
        if q == 3:
            self.image2.setPixmap(self.setka1)

            self.q = q + 1
            self.xis6 = 1
        elif self.q == 4:
            self.image2.setPixmap(self.setka12)
            self.q = self.q + 1
            self.ois6 = 1
        if q == 5:
            self.image2.setPixmap(self.setka1)

            self.q = q + 1
            self.xis6 = 1
        elif self.q == 6:
            self.image2.setPixmap(self.setka12)
            self.q = self.q + 1
            self.ois6 = 1
        if q == 7:
            self.image2.setPixmap(self.setka1)

            self.q = q + 1
            self.xis6 = 1
        elif self.q == 8:
            self.image2.setPixmap(self.setka12)
            self.q = self.q + 1
            self.ois6 = 1
        if q == 9:
            self.image2.setPixmap(self.setka1)
            self.q = self.q + 1
            self.xis6 = 1
    def hodo128(self):
        self.o13.setEnabled(False)
        q = self.q
        if q == 1:
            self.image123.setPixmap(self.setka1)

            self.q = q + 1
            self.xis7 = 1
        elif self.q == 2:
            self.image123.setPixmap(self.setka12)
            self.q = self.q + 1
            self.ois7 = 1
        if q == 3:
            self.image123.setPixmap(self.setka1)

            self.q = q + 1
            self.xis7 = 1
        elif self.q == 4:
            self.image123.setPixmap(self.setka12)
            self.q = self.q + 1
            self.ois7 = 1
        if q == 5:
            self.image123.setPixmap(self.setka1)

            self.q = q + 1
            self.xis7 = 1
        elif self.q == 6:
            self.image123.setPixmap(self.setka12)
            self.q = self.q + 1
            self.ois7 = 1
        if q == 7:
            self.image123.setPixmap(self.setka1)

            self.q = q + 1
            self.xis7 = 1
        elif self.q == 8:
            self.image123.setPixmap(self.setka12)
            self.q = self.q + 1
            self.ois7 = 1
        if q == 9:
            self.image123.setPixmap(self.setka1)
            self.q = self.q + 1
            self.xis7 = 1
    def hodo12(self):
        self.o12.setEnabled(False)
        q = self.q
        if q == 1:
            self.image12.setPixmap(self.setka1)

            self.q = q + 1
            self.xis8 = 1
        elif self.q == 2:
            self.image12.setPixmap(self.setka12)
            self.q = self.q + 1
            self.ois8 = 1
        if q == 3:
            self.image12.setPixmap(self.setka1)

            self.q = q + 1
            self.xis8 = 1
        elif self.q == 4:
            self.image12.setPixmap(self.setka12)
            self.q = self.q + 1
            self.ois8 = 1
        if q == 5:
            self.image12.setPixmap(self.setka1)

            self.q = q + 1
            self.xis8 = 1
        elif self.q == 6:
            self.image12.setPixmap(self.setka12)
            self.q = self.q + 1
            self.ois8 = 1
        if q == 7:
            self.image12.setPixmap(self.setka1)

            self.q = q + 1
            self.xis8 = 1
        elif self.q == 8:
            self.image12.setPixmap(self.setka12)
            self.q = self.q + 1
            self.ois8 = 1
        if q == 9:
            self.image12.setPixmap(self.setka1)
            self.q = self.q + 1
            self.xis8 = 1

    def hodo1(self):
        self.o1.setEnabled(False)
        q= self.q
        if q == 1 :
            self.image1.setPixmap(self.setka1)

            self.q = q +1
            self.xis9 = 1
        elif self.q == 2:
            self.image1.setPixmap(self.setka12)
            self.q = self.q +1
            self.ois9 = 1
        if q == 3:
            self.image1.setPixmap(self.setka1)

            self.q = q +1
            self.xis9 = 1
        elif self.q == 4:
            self.image1.setPixmap(self.setka12)
            self.q = self.q +1
            self.ois9 = 1
        if q == 5 :
            self.image1.setPixmap(self.setka1)

            self.q = q +1
            self.xis9 = 1
        elif self.q == 6:
            self.image1.setPixmap(self.setka12)
            self.q = self.q +1
            self.ois9 = 1
        if q == 7 :
            self.image1.setPixmap(self.setka1)

            self.q = q +1
            self.xis9 = 1
        elif self.q == 8:
            self.image1.setPixmap(self.setka12)
            self.q = self.q +1
            self.ois9 = 1
        if q == 9:

            self.image1.setPixmap(self.setka1)
            self.q = self.q+1
            self.xis9 = 1
            print(131)

    def x12(self):
        
        a = self.xis6
        a1 = self.xis3
        a2 = self.xis7
        a3 = self.xis8
        if a == 1:
            print(121)
            if a1 == 1:
                print('over3')
        else:
            if a3 == 1:
                print(1231)
                if a2 == 1:
                    print('over')









if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    wind = x_vs_o()

    wind.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1426640/%d0%9a%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b8-10-%d1%85-10/1427891#1427891 , https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1223023/%d0%9c%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0-%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b8-pyqt5/1223076#1223076 ?